# PRIVATE_KEY is not importing from .env file when deploying the contract using node.js

Tags: solidity

I put my private key in .env file and then import the .env file using require("dotenv").config() but still it is not compiling the code and throws an error. I even installed the dotenv using "yarn add dotenv".
In .env file, I put my private key as:
PRIVATE_KEY = "(private-key)";

In const wallet, I call the private key as : process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra"); //To import the 'fs' fuctionality of node.js to read the files of abi and bytecode
require("dotenv").config();
async function main() {
 
  await console.log("Smart contract address : 0x123456....");
  //include the provider and connect the local blockchain to our script
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "RPC-URL"
  );

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./Fundme_sol_Storage.abi", "utf8");

 //Here we've included our abi file and it readFileSync mainly takes two arguments obviously one is path of abi file and another is encoding for the smart contract

  const byteCode = fs.readFileSync("./Fundme_sol_Storage.bin", "utf8");

  //Now we have to use contract factory to deploy the smart contract on our local blockchain

  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, byteCode, wallet);
  console.log("Contract is deploying.....");
  const contractDeploy = await contractFactory.deploy();
  await contractDeploy.deployTransaction.wait(1);

  //This is going to give the number....

  const contractRet = await contractDeploy.retrieve();
  console.log(contractRet.toString());

  //This is going to increement the number..

  const contractStore = await contractDeploy.store("42");
  await contractStore.wait(1);

  //Now, we're going to retrieve number..

  const newNum = await contractDeploy.retrieve();
  console.log(`The update Fav number is:${newNum}`);
```

This is the error I am getting in terminal while deploying the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change to PRIVATE_KEY="803b89dh9f89"
sometimes it's okay with PRIVATE_KEY=803b89dh9f89 too

Answer (score 0):

my .env file :
[image]
my deploy.js:
[image]
Hope that helps, I'm a beginner

Comment: The next time include code and snippets as text. That way it is much easier if someone wants to use them.